# Getting the current user (aspnetcore identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to get the id of the current user (the user executing the method) with Identity package. The context is a UserManager<ApplicationUser> (ApplicationUser is an IdentityUser).

```
var currentUserId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

I add this to the list of claims when a user logs in. 'user' is the ApplicationUser from the DB.

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
```

I also used [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#usermanager-and-signinmanager) and added the following in Program.cs.

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

However, I keep getting an "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" error.

[The link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#usermanager-and-signinmanager) also showed that I could get the current user as

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

However, that just made the user null.

I'm using postman/swagger for debugging.

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Server.Authentication.Controllers.AuthController.UpdateUser(String id, UpdateModel model) in C:\i2\PromoCreate\promocreate\Server\Authentication\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 168
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling `await signInManager.PasswordSigninAsync(user, password, true)` or smth similar anywhere? This creates the `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` cookie. Without this cookie it'll obviously not work. Then you should also check whether or not you set your `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` somewhere in the Startup...

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question.
I simply needed the [Authorize] attribute above the method.